# Visual Studio 2019 Won't publish

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I've been running a .Core Project in VS 2019 for a while now and I've been building and publishing, but all of the sudden won't publish any more. I've Uninstalled and reinstalled and I get the same error.
[image: Error Thrown Not Helpful]

So I dug into the Stack Track / log I'm not seeing the issue.

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<IsBuildCompletedSuccessfully>b__2()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<DefaultCorePublishStep>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__213.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. <---

System.Exception: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.
```

===================

I've got nothing.

Comment: Does the Build Output window show anything?

Comment: @ESG Its has 2 warnings but still Runs and builds just fine.

Comment: What's the version of VS you use? And what's the target framework version for your .NET Core project?

Comment: @Lex Li  VS 2019  Version 16.4.1  Trying to publish Core 2.2

Comment: .NET Core 2.2 is end-of-life soon, so VS latest update seems to have disable certain things. I can still publish .NET Core 2.2 locally to a folder, which you might try too, but I guess if you want to publish to things like Azure App Service, it can fail.